# HIbernate optimistic locking only for certain updates

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, locking

I am looking into an issue in our system where two concurrently running transactions of a particular long operation try to update the same table row. As there is no locking currently, the transaction that commits second causes the updates of the first transaction to be lost. I would like to avoid this by optimistic locking.

The issue is that we don't have optimistic locking enabled currently. If I enable optimistic locking now by adding a dedicated version number column, this would then get enabled for every update on that table. The codebase is legacy and we are not aware of most parts of it. So, there might be other long running operations in the system which will start failing on enabling optimistic locking, some of these might even be OK to live with stale updates. Also, we would not like to introduce any new errors without knowing which parts of the system might be impacted.

So, my question:

Is there a way in hibernate to do optimistic locking for only certain updates.

From what I understood by reading hibernate documentation, using a dedicated version number or timestamp will enable optimistic locking on the table for every update.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't implement a lock by yourself?

Comment: @ShawnSong Can you explain how I can do that , without breaking my transaction.

Comment: Create a new table which stores only version numbers and check the version number before your updates.